# Applying the JQUERY effects to AJAX ModelPopUpExtender

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Is it possible to give the ***JQUERY UI effects*** like fadeIn, fadeOut, **animate** or simply **fade** effect to the AJAX *ModelPopUpExtender* (asp.net c# page) when it gets poped up...??

like when the button to display or pop this Model popup extender will be clicked, the extender will appear with the JQUERY effects...

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/1318051/2624063.aspx#2624063

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try using this for example:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "fadein",
            hide: "fadeout"
        });
```

This solution was based on their documentation here - http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi shanabus.. thanx for your reply...but i have to implement the effects on the ModelPopUpExtender(as it is coming from the server side)...how could i use the dialog feature with ajax model popup exten...??

Comment: can you post some of your code so that I could provide a better answer?